# Python/Numpy - Extracting Bits of Bytes

Tags: python, numpy

I have 8 bytes of data in the form of a `numpy.frombuffer()` array.  I need to get bits 10-19 into a variable and bits 20-29 into a variable.  How do I use Python to extract bits that cross bytes?   I've read about bit shifting but it isn't clear to me if that is the way to do it.

Comment: could you explain your question with an example

Comment: numpy won't help you here with bit manipulation (though it is a great library). better to just stick with python `bytes` objects (like the buffer you used probably already was). See my answer for an example using `bytes` (byte string)

Comment: @Aaron I would advise against making such strong comments unless one is absolutely sure about it.

Comment: @Ehsan I don't think it's that strong a statement. Numpy may be capable of doing this, but it won't make it easier or more understandable. Particularly for a new programmer, I tend to recommend sticking to the standard library, and built-in functions until you're more comfortable with the language.

Comment: @Aaron I was referring to this comment _numpy won't help you here with bit manipulation_ . What you replied is a totally understandable approach and a different comment.

Comment: @Kevin what is your data type? do you have an example of your buffer data that you can provide us?

Comment: The data is an integer.  I'll see if I can pull example data.

Comment: @Kevin Please see if the proposed approach resolves your case. If not, please provide us with and example input and expected output so we can help better. Thank you

Comment: @Aaron Please refer to my solution for understandability and easy to use numpy solution compared to python standard modules. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Get each bit individually by indexing the correct byte, then masking off the correct bit. Then you can shift and add to build your new number from the bits.

```
data = b'abcdefgh' #8 bytes of data

def bit_slice(data, start, stop):
    out = 0
    for i in range(start, stop):
        byte_n = i//8
        byte_bit = i%8
        byte_mask = 1<<byte_bit
        bit = bool(data[byte_n] & byte_mask)
        out = out*2 + bit #multiply by 2 is equivalent to shift. Then add the new bit
    return out
```

re:comments

Each time we want to add a new bit to our number like so:

> 10110 
> 101101

We have to shift the first five bits over and then either add 1 or 0 based on what the value of the next bit is. Shifting to the left moves each digit one place higher, which in binary means multiply by 2. In decimal shifting a number over one place means multiply by 10. When adding the new bit to our number we're accumulating I simply multiply by 2 instead of using the right shift operator just to show it's another option. When creating the byte mask, I did use the right shift operator (`<<`). It works by shifting a 1 several places over so I end up with a byte that has a 1 in just the right place that when I "and" it with the byte in question, I get just the single bit I want to index:

> 1<<3 = 00001000 
> 1<<5 = 00100000 
> 1<<0 = 00000001 
> 1<<7 = 10000000

then apply the mask to get the bit we want:

> 10011011 #a byte of data 
> 00100000 #bit mask for the 32's place 
> _________& 
> 00**0**00000 
>  #bit in the 32's place is 0

> 10011011 #a byte of data 
> 00010000 #bit mask for the 16's place 
> _________& 
> 000**1**0000 
>  #bit in the 16's place is 1

After applying the mask, if the selected bit is 0 than the entire number will always be 0. If the selected bit is 1 the number will always be greater than 0. Calling `bool` on that result is equivalent to:

```
if data[byte_n] & byte_mask > 0:
    bit = 1
else:
    bit = 0
```

... because a boolean interpreted as an integer is simply a 1 or a 0.

Comment: Can you please explain "Multiply by 2 is equivalent to shift"?

Comment: Also, I don't get the calculation of the byte_mask.  Can you explain more?

Comment: @Kevin see edit

Comment: Thanks, @Aaron, for the extra explanation.  This makes sense now.  Your solution is what I'm experimenting with for now.

Comment: @Kevin Ehsan's solution is also correct, and is certainly shorter, but I hope mine gives a bit more understanding on how it works under the hood...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your datatype you might need to slightly modify this numpy solution:

```
a = np.frombuffer(b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08', dtype=np.uint8)
#array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=uint8)
```

unpacking bits:

```
first = np.unpackbits(a)[10:20]
#array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

And if you need to repack the bits:

```
first_packed = np.packbits(first)
array([8, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

Please note that python is **0-based index** and if you want 10th-19th element, please adjust the above indexing to `np.unpackbits(a)[9:19]`.

Similarly for other case:

```
second = np.unpackbits(a)[20:30]
#array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: thanks for this.  It is easy and understandable.  My initial data is 8 bytes.  I need to understand from management whether all data will be 8 bytes.

Comment: @Kevin you are welcome. Please feel free to edit your question when you have more information about it and comment here for us to relook at it.